# Prevent exit(1) from exiting Python when executing C-function from Python

Tags: python, c, multithreading, ctypes, exit

I'm executing a C function from python using ctypes. Under certain conditions, the C function I'm calling exits using exit(1), and I am not in a position where I can change this behaviour. I wish for my Python program to keep running even after this exit signal. I've attempted using threading to solve the issue; however, my program still exits on the exit signal.

my_lib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void c_func(int i)
{
    if(i == 3)
        exit(1);
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

my_program.py

```
from ctypes import *
import threading
lib = CDLL("my_lib.so")
for i in range(8):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=lib.c_func, args=(i))
    thread.start()
```

*Desired output on running my_program.py:*
0124567

*Actual output:*
012

Comment: You could avoid calling it if `i==3`, but I'm guessing you won't find that a very satisfying answer.

Comment: I don't think you can do this. `exit` is terminating the process and there is nothing you can do about it, except running it in a different process.

Comment: Yep. Threading won't help, you need a separate process. Oh, and don't forget to file a bug ticket, because libraries should generally refrain from calling `exit()`.

Comment: Why don't you use `return ;` statement in `c_func()` ?

Comment: @veysel I assume the *actual* function the OP has no control over and this is a toy example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A multiprocessing solution works:

```py
import ctypes as ct
import multiprocessing as mp

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.c_func.argtypes = ct.c_int,
dll.c_func.restype = None

def func(i):
    dll.c_func(i)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ps = [mp.Process(target=func, args=(i,)) for i in range(8)]
    for p in ps:
        p.start()
    for p in ps:
        p.join()
```

Output from running in parallel so output varies.  Put the `join` inside the first `for` to run serially:

```
0125647
```

Answer (score 1):

Running the function in a subprocess is a solution that suited my needs:

my_lib.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void c_func(int i)
{
    if(i == 3)
        exit(1);
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

my_program.py

```
import subprocess
for i in range(8):
    subprocess.run(['python3', f'my_func_call.py {i}'])
```

my_func_call.py

```
import sys
from ctypes import *
lib = CDLL("my_lib.so")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lib.c_func(sys.argv[1]) # c_func(i)
```

*Output:*
0124567